# Using greater than 0 in a find(:all, :conditions =>{}) statement in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying (and failing) to construct a find all statement with conditions in rails for what I need. I need to find all the values where where the 'in' value in a table is greater than 0 (or just not zero would be fine) but I am having trouble with this, here's what I need:

```
@sales = Transaction.find(:all, :conditions => {:in => 'greater than 0'} )
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Arel to do this without having to reach into SQL:

```
@sales = Transaction.where(Transaction.arel_table[:in].gt(0)).all
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  @sales = Transaction.find(:all, :conditions => ['in > ?', 0] )
```

OR use conditions like

```
  :conditions => 'in > 0'
```

Comment: I had tried this but for some reason this gives me invalid SQL

Comment: Got it... it is happening because 'in' is a reserve keyword in mysql. So Kelly's solution will work.